# Regex to match mixed Arabic and numbers

Tags: php, regex

```
return preg_match('/^(\d*\p{Arabic}+*)$/iu', $str);
```

I'm using the function above in order to match string such as:
- "somewordinArabic"
- "3somewordinArabic" etc

But i want it to match also cases like:
- "3somewordin444Arabic"
- "somethingarabic22"

So basically mixed arabic with numbers, with the exepcetion that at least one letter is in arabic,

Can someone help me?

Comment: I just found an answer, to use a grouping: return preg_match('/^[\d\p{Arabic}]*$/iu', $str);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^[\d\p{Arabic}]*\p{Arabic}[\d\p{Arabic}]*$/ui
```

Comment: How can we use this to find matching arabic word or words using javascript