# validating input as name for Arabic character

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a input and I need to check it for just alphabet characters (as a Name, e.g peter). here is my code: *(but it works just for english characters)*

```
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
  $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
}
```

How can I create a `regex` for Arabic character ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `\p{L}` to match any kind of letter from any language.

```
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
if (!preg_match("/^[\p{L} ]+$/u",$name)) {
  $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
}
```

Remove the space character from the character class, if you don't want.

Comment: thanks, but is it possible to you edit your regex for checking if `$name == ''` return false ?

Comment: just replace * with +

Comment: aha I see, just onething, your solution is good for both English character and Arabic characters. Is it possible to it be just or Arabic ? (return false for English (like numbers and symbols)).

Comment: try  `preg_match("/^\p{Arabic}+$/u", $name)` if you want to include space, ``preg_match("/^[\p{Arabic} ]+$/u", $name)``

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match("/\p{Arabic}/u", $name)
```

should do it for you

Comment: Edit your solution and remove `]` character.

Comment: Also please edit your solution and add sensitivity to numbers and symbols. I need just alphabet characters.

Comment: @Sajad sorry but I can you please explain what you meant by adding sensitivity to numbers and symbols ?

Comment: `$name = 'سلام 1';` return false, for character `1`.

Comment: take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809605/regex-to-match-mixed-arabic-and-numbers